# How can I fix my Oracle 11G SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with my query here.

```
SELECT ORDER#, SUM(PAIDEACH * QUANTITY) AS TOTAL 
    FROM ORDERITEMS 
    WHERE TOTAL > 39.9 
    GROUP BY ORDER# 
    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
"TOTAL": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to have a predicate on your aggregate function, you can use a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT ORDER#, SUM(PAIDEACH * QUANTITY) AS TOTAL 
  FROM ORDERITEMS 
 GROUP BY ORDER# 
HAVING SUM(PAIDEACH * QUANTITY) > 39.9
 ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an alias in your `WHERE` clause then you can place your query inside of another `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ORDER#, SUM(PAIDEACH * QUANTITY) AS TOTAL 
    FROM ORDERITEMS 
    GROUP BY ORDER# 
) x
WHERE x.TOTAL > 39.9 
ORDER BY x.TOTAL DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`order by 2 desc` (numeric references to columns start with 1)

There is no need to write nested queries or even putting a `having` clause to your query. Just refer to the column with a numeral, but don't forget to change it when you change the query ;-)

Comment: The error is from the `where`, not the `order by`; the column alias is valid by there.